# python - Global name XXX is not defined on RPI interrupt

Tags: python, global-variables, global

I am new to python with the Raspberry Pi.   Below is a example program to use the GPIO. My problem is that in my conditional I cannot see to have any variables span to other statements in the block

The entire program is included the example of the problem code is as follows:

### Turn on GPIO pin 23

```
            print uptime
```

NameError: global name 'uptime' is not defined

Any suggestions?

Thank in advance

**************************** python code  *****************************************

## !/usr/bin/env python2.7

import time;

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep     # this lets us have a time delay (see line 12)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)     # set up BCM GPIO numbering
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)    # set GPIO17 as input (button)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 23 to OUT

GPIO.output(23,False) ## Turn off GPIO pin 23

## Define a threaded callback function to run in another thread when events are detected

def  my_callback(channel):

```
global start_time, uptime




    if GPIO.input(17):     # if port 17 == 1
            end_time = time.time()
            #print (end_time)
        print "Rising edge detected on 17"
            uptime = end_time - start_time            
            #uptime = int(uptime)
            print uptime
            GPIO.output(23,False) 
            ## Turn off GPIO pin 2




    elif (GPIO.input(17)== 0):
            start_time = time.time()
            #print (start_time)
        print "Falling edge detected on 17"
            GPIO.output(23,True) 
            ## Turn on GPIO pin 23
            print uptime
```

## when a changing edge is detected on port 17, regardless of whatever

## else is happening in the program, the function my_callback will be run

GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)

raw_input("Press Enter when ready\n>")

try:
    print "When pressed, you'll see: Rising Edge detected on 17"
    print "When released, you'll see: Falling Edge detected on 17"
    sleep(10)         # wait 30 seconds
    print "Time's up. Finished!"
    print uptime
finally:                   # this block will run no matter how the try block exits
    GPIO.cleanup()         # clean up after yourself

Comment: Ouch. Please fix the formatting!

Answer (score 0):

If, the first time `my_callback` gets called, `GPIO.input(17)` is 1, then you'll set `uptime` and everything will be fine.

But what happens if the first time it's called, `GPIO.input(17)` is 0? Then you *won't* set `uptime`. And, because this is the first time you've ever called this function, and you don't have any *other* code that sets `uptime`, it hasn't been set yet. But you try to `print` it anyway. So you get a `NameError`.

You could fix this by, e.g., setting it to an initial value at the start of the problem—e.g.:

```
def my_callback(channel):
    # your existing code

uptime = 0
```

---

Of course I'm assuming some reasonable indentation for your code. As pasted, your code is just a mess of `IndentationError` exceptions and won't do *anything*, and it's quite possible that your real code has other bugs caused by code not being indented under the right flow control statement.

And, since it looks like you may be mixing tabs and spaces, making indentation errors hard to spot: Get yourself a better text editor, which automatically converts tabs into spaces, auto-indents for you, and/or shows tabs in some visible way. Or at least run your code with the `-tt` flag to catch tabs as errors so you can fix them.

---

As a side note, your `elif` is definitely wasteful, and possibly even broken.

If the `if GPIO.input(17):` part didn't trigger, then you *know* the result is 0 (or something else falsey, but since `input` only returns numbers, it can only be 0). So, why test it again for `0` when it can't be anything else?

But meanwhile, you're not just re-testing a value here unnecessarily, you're actually going out and *reading* the value again off the hardware. So, if the edge changes from 1 to 0 and back to 1 quickly enough, your first read may return 0, then your second read may return 1, meaning neither of your branches fires. (Plus, by reading, you *may* have also absorbed the edge trigger so you don't get another callback, although I'm not sure about that.)

You can solve all of these problems by just using `else:` instead of trying to write an `elif` that exactly captures the opposite sense of the `if`.